# How to access methods that takes array as argument,without argument?(java)

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, arguments, call

im quite a beginner in Java and im facing a problem with my code.Bascially I have a class containing a method that create a listarray based on user input:

```
public class manage{
public void adding() { 
    boolean loop = true;
    ArrayList<Game> thegame = new ArrayList<Game>();
    while(loop) {
        Scanner agame = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("name: \n");
        String Cgame = agame.nextLine();
        Scanner qty = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("the qty: \n");
        int CQty = qty.nextInt();


        Console wertgame = new Console(Cgame,Cqty);
        thegame.add(new Game(Cgame,Cqty));

        System.out.println("continue?");
        Scanner autre = new Scanner(System.in);
        int continu = other.nextInt();
        if(continu==1) {

        }
        else if(continu==2) {
            Main.menu();
        }
    }

    return thegame; 
}
```

And then I have another method in the same class that is to display it:

```
public void information(List<Game> thegame) {  
        System.out.print(thegame);

    }}
```

The problem im having here, is that I need to access the information(List thegame) method, from another class(java file).However,how do I access it from my other class since I cant access(call) it using "manage.information()"since it needs argument,but my arraylist isnt created yet in my other class,it gets create only when in the manage class.So I cant pass the arguments when calling it.How do I access/call it from my other class then?

thank you

Comment: Move `List<Game> thegame` from a local variable to a field in the class.

Comment: public class Manage{ private ArrayList<Game> theGame = new ArrayList<Game>(); public void adding(){ ...

Comment: [Java Tutorials. Understanding Class Members.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: @Phil_oneil read java convention, because your code has a lot of small pesky mistakes. It is difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't.

If you want to call a method that requires an argument, then you need to pass that argument in some form or another.

IMO, the best solution would simply be to not call the `information` method at the point where you don't have the argument it requires.  The sole purpose of the method seems to be to print out its argument, so if you don't have an object (list) to print then the method call *cannot* do anything worthwhile.

Alternatively, you could pass a `null` instead of a list, but that will simply result in the method outputting `"null"` which seems rather pointless.

In short, you can't pass an argument that doesn't exist.  It simply makes no sense.  Think again about what you are actually trying to do here.